# How to get sheet name or index currently being viewed?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is [Sample Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/us10y.jpg)

I need sheet name or index currently being viewed. 
because there are many sheets so, It depends on when user click on a document.
I don't to put any specific numbers or letters here. 
Thanks.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[?];  <==   
var range = ss.getRange("D5:D42");
range.copyValuesToRange(ss, 9, 9, 5, 42);
```

or

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('?'); <==
var range = ss.getRange("D5:D42");
range.copyValuesToRange(ss, 9, 9, 5, 42);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. About `var sheet = ss.getSheets()[?];`

`sheet` is one dimensional array. The array includes the sheet information in the spreadsheet. `?` of `[?]` means the index of array. From your image, in your case, 0, 1, 2 and 3 for `?` are 1, 2, 3, 4 for the sheet name, respectively.

#### 2. About `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('?');`

In this case, it requires the sheet name. The sheet name can be retrieved by `getSheetName()`. The sample script for your script is as follows.

```
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheets = s.getSheets();
for (var i in sheets) {
  var sheetname = sheets[i].getSheetName();
  if (sheetname == "### sheet name you need ###") {
    var ss = s.getSheetByName(sheetname);
    var range = ss.getRange("D5:D42");
    range.copyValuesToRange(ss, 9, 9, 5, 42);
  }
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for getActiveSheet

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getActiveSheet()

Answer (score 0):

As long as ...

A) the script was created from the Tools menu of a Google Sheet (i.e. they are linked), and

B) an onEdit trigger has been setup for that script (using Edit > "Current project's triggers"),

... the following should successfully deliver the **sheet name, cell address, username of the editor and content of the edit made**; sending an email to a specified address for monitoring:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: 'example@gmail.com',
    subject: 'An update has been detected in the spreadsheet',
    htmlBody:
      'In cell ' + e.range.getA1Notation() + </br>' + 
      'of sheet ' + e.source.getSheetName() + </br>' + 
      'the user ' + e.user + </br>' + 
      'entered this value:' + e.value + </br>' + 
      'Thanks!'
    }
  );
}
```

(You need to **save** the script, once you've pasted in the code and changed example@gmail.com for a real monitoring address, before it will start detecting changes)